# Prove that $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges using Cauchy test ($|x_{n+p} - x_n|$)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Stopped at this step:
$$|x_{n+p} - x_n| = |\sum^{n+p}_{k = n+ 1}\frac{1}{k^2}| = \sum^{n+p}_{k = n+ 1}\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \dots +\frac{1}{(n+p)^2}$$
Don’t know how to reduce p or give an estimate

Comment: Have you considered bounding the sum by an integral (as in the integral test)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*:

$$\frac 1{m^2}<\frac 1{m(m-1)}=\frac1{m-1}-\frac1m$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: This is clearly not true. If $m=1$ then you're implying that $1\lt1/2$

Comment: It should be $\frac{1}{m^2}<\frac{1}{m(m-1)}=\frac{1}{m-1}-\frac{1}{m}$ for $m\ge2$.